# Why do the list elements not swap?

Tags: java, android, drag-and-drop, android-recyclerview

I have a `RecyclerView` and have implemented an `onMove` command called `onItemMove`. I'm using `onItemMove` to try and get the list elements to swap position when dragged around, but the list elements just hover over each, they don't swap. How can I correct this?

Note 1: `onItemDismiss` works fine; it swipes the item away and removes it from the list.

Note 2: I've tried to `Override` `onItemMove`, but it doesn't actually override its superclass.

**List Adaptor Class:** This contains the onItemMove command

```
public class ListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ListAdapter.ListViewHolder> {
    private static final String TAG = "ListAdapter";
    Context context;
    private List<UserData> dataList = new ArrayList<>();
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    Listener listener;
    DbHelper dbHelper;



    public interface Listener {
        void nameToChnge(String name);
    }

    public ListAdapter(Context context, List<UserData> dataList1) {
        this.context = context;
        this.dataList = dataList1;
        this.listener= (Listener) context;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }


    @Override
    public ListViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.recylerview_one, parent, false);
        ListViewHolder viewHolder = new ListViewHolder(convertView);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ListViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        holder.tv_name.setText(dataList.get(position).name);
        holder.tv_quantity.setText(dataList.get(position).quantity);
        holder.tv_description.setText(dataList.get(position).description + "");

        holder.relLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String s = dataList.get(position).id;
                Integer stringo = Integer.parseInt(s);
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, ItemEditActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("ItemNumber", stringo);
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return dataList.size();
    }

    class ListViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView tv_name, tv_quantity, tv_description;
        RelativeLayout relLayout;


        public ListViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            tv_name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.nameDisplay);
            tv_quantity = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.quantityDisplay);
            tv_description = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.descriptionDisplay);
            relLayout = (RelativeLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.relLayout);
        }
    }



    public void onItemDismiss(final int position) {
        dataList.remove(position);
        notifyItemRemoved(position);

    }

    public void onItemMove(int fromPosition, int toPosition) {
        Collections.swap(dataList, fromPosition, toPosition);
        notifyItemMoved(fromPosition, toPosition);

    }
}
```

**ItemTouchHelper Class:**

```
  public class SimpleItemTouchHelperCallback extends ItemTouchHelper.Callback{
        private final ListAdapter  mAdapter;


        public SimpleItemTouchHelperCallback(ListAdapter adapter) {
            mAdapter = adapter;
        }

        @Ov

erride
    public boolean isLongPressDragEnabled() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isItemViewSwipeEnabled() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int getMovementFlags(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
        int dragFlags = ItemTouchHelper.UP | ItemTouchHelper.DOWN;
        int swipeFlags = ItemTouchHelper.START | ItemTouchHelper.END;
        return makeMovementFlags(dragFlags, swipeFlags);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMove(RecyclerView recyclerView,
                          RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder,
                          RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
        mAdapter.onItemMove(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition(), target.getAdapterPosition());

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
        mAdapter.onItemDismiss(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
    }
}
```

**Part of the Main Activity where I initialise the `RecyclerView` and 
SimpleItemTouchHelperCallback:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ListAdapter.Listener {
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    DbHelper dbHelper;
    ListAdapter adapter;
    FloatingActionButton fab;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        introItem();
        dbHelper = DbHelper.getInstance(getApplicationContext());

        recyclerView= (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rv_contactlist);
        adapter = new ListAdapter(this, dbHelper.getAllUser());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        ItemTouchHelper.Callback callback =
                new SimpleItemTouchHelperCallback(adapter);
        ItemTouchHelper touchHelper = new ItemTouchHelper(callback);
        touchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);

        totalQuantity();

        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        fabHideShow();
        versionCheckMethod();

    }
```

Comment: Post the code where you create and initialise the RecyclerView and  SimpleItemTouchHelperCallback

Comment: @AnuragSingh I think I've provided the required info, correct me if I haven't

Comment: You are very correct. Thanks and I will revert very soon.

Comment: Regards "Note 2": `RecyclerView.Adapter` doesn't have a `onItemMove()` method - so why would you try overriding a method that doesn't exist ?

Answer (score 4):

You just need to study the code of this sample and implement it: https://github.com/iPaulPro/Android-ItemTouchHelper-Demo/tree/master/app/src/main/java/co/paulburke/android/itemtouchhelperdemo

But basically what you need is to create two interfaces. The first one:

```
public interface ItemTouchHelperAdapter {
/**
 * Called when an item has been dragged far enough to trigger a move. This is called every time
 * an item is shifted, and not at the end of a "drop" event.
 *
 * @param fromPosition The start position of the moved item.
 * @param toPosition   Then end position of the moved item.

 */
void onItemMove(int fromPosition, int toPosition);


/**
 * Called when an item has been dismissed by a swipe.
 *
 * @param position The position of the item dismissed.

 */
void onItemDismiss(int position);
}
```

And the second one:

```
public interface ItemTouchHelperViewHolder {
    /**
      * Implementations should update the item view to indicate it's active state.
     */
    void onItemSelected();


    /**
     * state should be cleared.
     */
    void onItemClear();
}
```

The in the SimpleItemTouchHelperCallback something like that:

```
public class SimpleItemTouchHelperCallback extends ItemTouchHelper.Callback {

    private final ItemTouchHelperAdapter mAdapter;

    public SimpleItemTouchHelperCallback(ItemTouchHelperAdapter adapter) {
        mAdapter = adapter;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isLongPressDragEnabled() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isItemViewSwipeEnabled() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public int getMovementFlags(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
        final int dragFlags = ItemTouchHelper.UP | ItemTouchHelper.DOWN;
        final int swipeFlags = ItemTouchHelper.START | ItemTouchHelper.END;
        return makeMovementFlags(dragFlags, swipeFlags);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMove(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder source, RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
        mAdapter.onItemMove(source.getAdapterPosition(), target.getAdapterPosition());
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
        mAdapter.onItemDismiss(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onSelectedChanged(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int actionState) {
        if (actionState != ItemTouchHelper.ACTION_STATE_IDLE) {
            ItemTouchHelperViewHolder itemViewHolder = (ItemTouchHelperViewHolder) viewHolder;
            itemViewHolder.onItemSelected();
        }

        super.onSelectedChanged(viewHolder, actionState);
    }

    @Override
    public void clearView(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
        super.clearView(recyclerView, viewHolder);

        ItemTouchHelperViewHolder itemViewHolder = (ItemTouchHelperViewHolder) viewHolder;
        itemViewHolder.onItemClear();
    }
}
```

Then you have to change the RecyclerViewAdapter, and implement there the `onItemMove` method as we said in the oder comments. And you should implemement also the `onStartDragListener` like so:

```
    public interface OnStartDragListener {
    /**
     * Called when a view is requesting a start of a drag.
     *
     * @param viewHolder The holder of the view to drag.
     */
    void onStartDrag(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder);
}
```

And then use it in your adapter onBindViewHolder (remember to implement all the interfaces in the class declaration) like this (You need to change this code based on your variable name):

```
holder.handleView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (MotionEventCompat.getActionMasked(event) == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    mDragStartListener.onStartDrag(holder);
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Where mDragListener is a `OnStartDragListener` variable.

Finally check this guide for more: http://valokafor.com/remember-drag-and-drop-position-with-recyclerview/

Comment: I've tried this, however I get an error and can't implement it because `Override` does not override its super class

Comment: your method is "public void" though, the parent method id a "public boolean". Try to change it, or just use ctrl+o and see if you can add it from the list.

Comment: I had tried a boolean, and just copy pasted your code but still the same error. Sorry, I've never used ctrl+o before - what am I looking for? Screen shot: http://puu.sh/unuvj/b3984a734b.png

Comment: I aslso suggest to look at this code sample : https://github.com/iPaulPro/Android-ItemTouchHelper-Demo

Comment: Basically ctrl+o let you choose the methods you can @Override.

Comment: Yes, that was the tutorial I initially followed, but still can't solve my error after spending a fair bit of time on the same github you linked

Comment: try to change your onItemMove code with this:
@Override
    public boolean onItemMove(int fromPosition, int toPosition) {
        Collections.swap(mItems, fromPosition, toPosition);
        notifyItemMoved(fromPosition, toPosition);
        return true;
    }

Comment: same error: "method does not override method from its superclass"

Comment: Because in your adapter you should have: 
implements ItemTouchHelperAdapter

Comment: the full declaration of your adapter should be:
public class ListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ListAdapter.ListViewHolder> implements ItemTouchHelperAdapter

Comment: Ah, yeah that makes sense. Are you sure it should be `ItemTouchHelperAdapter`? I'm getting an error saying it can't resolve it

Comment: Another think. In your onMove method you should add before your code an if/else statement, like:

if (viewHolder.getItemViewType() != target.getItemViewType()) {
            return false;
        }

Comment: According to the sample code, yes. Check this: https://github.com/iPaulPro/Android-ItemTouchHelper-Demo/blob/master/app/src/main/java/co/paulburke/android/itemtouchhelperdemo/RecyclerListAdapter.java

Comment: public class ListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerListAdapter.ItemViewHolder>
        implements ItemTouchHelperAdapter

That is the correct one. You use a ListView instance and not a Recyclearview one.

Comment: Okay, I'll go through this tonight - thanks for your help, I'll get back to you asap

Comment: I have modified the answer with all the correct steps and code you should use. Please let me know if everything works!

Comment: Sorry, I've tried implementing your code but still struggling. A copy and paste of your class declaration changes immediately throws a spanner in the works, I don't know where your getting `ItemTouchHelperAdapter`, or why you changed `RecyclerView.Adapter<ListAdapter.ListViewHolder>` - Sorry if I'm acting dense, but can't figure if you've got classes I haven't

Comment: That is a class you should declare, like this: https://github.com/iPaulPro/Android-ItemTouchHelper-Demo/blob/master/app/src/main/java/co/paulburke/android/itemtouchhelperdemo/helper/ItemTouchHelperAdapter.java

Comment: You should try to use the classes in the helper folder in the sample. Study the code and try to replicate it. And if you can't I am here to help

Comment: Okay, I thought my `SimpleItemTouchHelperCallback` class was handling the move and swipe calls, is it not?

Comment: Yes, but this method is what listen for a move event. Does It works?

Comment: Your exact code, no, it can't resolve the changes to extend and implement

Comment: No I know, intact I gave him a link with the sample code to follow.

Comment: okay, I have no implemented the adaptor, and am overriding the onMove and onItemDismiss commands - but still no swapping

Comment: I suggest also to see the onStartDrag interface, and it's implementation on the recyclerView adapter class.

Comment: Okay, I'll work on that tomorrow. Thanks for being patient with me

Comment: Don't worry, I understand the frustration when something doesn't as expected. I suggest to read the entire sample, all the classes and try to do the same. And most important, try to understand everything.

Comment: I found this two well made guides: First one http://valokafor.com/remember-drag-and-drop-position-with-recyclerview/ and the second one http://androidessence.com/swipe-to-dismiss-recyclerview-items/

Comment: This is the part you are interested that refers to the second guide: http://androidessence.com/drag-and-drop-recyclerview-items/

Comment: Yes you are right. I just provided the links because I was working. I will provide the essential code as soon as possible.

Comment: I don't understand why people comment under an answer, then leave a -1, and the cancel the answer! We are just trying to help here!

Comment: I've been busy and haven't fully implemented your advice, however you've been a lot of help so have the bounty and possibly also the answer when I get to the bottom of this, thanks